# ConditionType error message when uploading feed with "_POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_" using amazon MWS

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I want to upload my product to "amazon.com" with the feed template "**_POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_**" using amazon MWS from my website.

When it submitted the feed through amazon mws then i am facing the following error:

> "The ConditionType for SKU: [MYSKU] is invalid. See the Data
>   Definitions tab of your inventory template for valid ConditionType
>   options."

it was working fine for "Jewelry" category in amazon.com.

but now when i upload my product under "Jewelry" category with feed 
template "_POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_" using amazon MWS and submit feed, then i have the above mentioned issue but products were created with incomplete status and available quantity become zero.

I have provided quantity greater than zero.

After that i have download sample feed template for "Jewelry" category from "sellercentral.amazon.com" and check it then there is no option to add `ConditionType` in amazon sample feed template.

Then i also add `ConditionType` field in product template manualy and submitted through amazon mws but facing same issue but products were created with incomplete status and available quantity become zero, but i have provided quantity greater than zero.

I have tried to upload my feed product template "Add product via upload" section of amazon sellercentral then facing same problem

```
MarketplaceWebServiceConfig config = new MarketplaceWebServiceConfig();
                                    config.ServiceURL = accountDetails.ServiceURL;
                                    config.SetUserAgentHeader(
                                        "Amazon Listion",
                                        "1.0",
                                        "C#",
                                        "<Parameter 1>", "<Parameter 2>");
                                    MarketplaceWebService.MarketplaceWebService service = new MarketplaceWebServiceClient(accountDetails.AWSAccessKeyID, accountDetails.SecretKey, config);
                                    SubmitFeedRequest request = new SubmitFeedRequest();
                                    request.Merchant = accountDetails.MerchantId;
                                    request.MWSAuthToken = accountDetails.MWSAuthToken; // Optional

                                    request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
                                    request.MarketplaceIdList.Id = new List<string>(new string[] { accountDetails.MarketplaceID });
                                    request.FeedContent = System.IO.File.Open(FeedContent.FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                                    request.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
                                    request.FeedContent.Position = 0;
                                    request.FeedType = "_POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_";
                                    SubmitFeedResponse response = service.SubmitFeed(request);
                                    long FeedId = CommonUtilities.ToInt64(response.SubmitFeedResult.FeedSubmissionInfo.FeedSubmissionId);
                                    request.FeedContent.Close();
                                    SMAmazonSubmitFeedResponse feedResponse = new SMAmazonSubmitFeedResponse();
                                    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                                    if (FeedId > 0)
                                    {
                                        feedResponse.TemplateId = templateId;
                                        feedResponse.FeedId = FeedId;
```

please guide me how to fix the issue and product listing with active status.

Comment: How is your question connected with C# ?

Comment: I have developed it in C#

Comment: please consider reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add the corresponding code snippets

Answer (score 0):

This should have been posted on https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/ instead. Also your xsd has a dependency on amzn-base.xsd which you will find has the list of ConditionType

```
##################################################
# Condition Info
##################################################

-->
<xsd:complexType name="ConditionInfo">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="ConditionType"/>
        <xsd:element name="ConditionNote" type="TwoThousandString" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="ConditionType">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="New"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="UsedLikeNew"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="UsedVeryGood"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="UsedGood"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="UsedAcceptable"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CollectibleLikeNew"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CollectibleVeryGood"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CollectibleGood"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CollectibleAcceptable"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Refurbished"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Club"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<!--
```